# Which control to use for quick text input (inputbox)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, messagebox, inputbox

I need a quick text input dialog box (MessageBox with a single text box in it). Is there any control available or should I use a form?

I just want user to enter some ID. And in other occasion I want 2 texboxes for username and password.

Comment: It always baffled why there has never been one build into the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll has an [InputBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox.aspx) method which you can use from C# to get a single string.

For example (Add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll first)

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

string response = Interaction.InputBox("Enter a string:", "MyApp", "DefaultString", 0, 0);
```

Othewise, you'll have to make your own form.

Comment: Is there anyway to make the InputBox use a "*" input mask so it can be used as a password form?

Comment: @AdamJakiela: No; you need to create your own form.

Comment: It is also necessary to [add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4369070/1497596).

Answer (score 0):

simple one is inputbox