# getting user input in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

is there a way to get user input like an inputbox in c#? i would like a window to pop up to ask a user to enter a string

Comment: Could you clarify? Windows forms? Web forms? Console App?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which control to use for quick text input (inputbox)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643924/which-control-to-use-for-quick-text-input-inputbox)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C# itself doesn't have such a feature, assuming you're using Winforms, but you can steal one from VB.NET's default libraries (from the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace):

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
       var response = Interaction.InputBox("Enter some text!", "Title", "Default text");
    }
}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox.aspx) for more info.

You could also create your own window using WinForms (or WPF) if you need it to do something more specific.

Comment: Don't forget to add assembly reference Microsoft.VisualBasic