# Cannot get InputBox after adding reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I did what is said here http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-1899493.php
  but in intellisense I only get Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider ???

step 1: Add refernce Microsoft.VisualBasic

step 2:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string result = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("kkk","text", "", 10, 20);

  MessageBox.Show(result);
}
```

Comment: I tried several times then it didn't work now I tried again it did work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Check if you really added the reference ;-)

`Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider` is located in `System.dll`, which is referenced for every new project. It seems to me as if you're not referencing `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, not to the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatability` library.