# Display a dialogbox with a text input in C#

Tags: c#, .net, programming-languages, input, dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which control to use for quick text input (inputbox)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643924/which-control-to-use-for-quick-text-input-inputbox)

I need to display a dialog box which contains an input text to let the user type something and press ok, so I can read the typed text and do other things.

Is there anyone who knows the name of it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the InputBox from VB6 by referencing the DLL.  Here is a link on how to do this in C#:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/InputBox.aspx

Answer (score 8):

There is no such a thing in C#. You have to create dialogbox with input on your own. Take a look [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/inputbox/), there is a good example how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Interaction.InputBox()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox.aspx) method, which comes within Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace. You can use it in C# project by simply adding Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll assembly reference.