# Does C# have some function that Input a String with a Form?

Tags: c#, string, delphi, function, input

I want the write a simple application, that input some strings, and do something with it.

I search for a function that is similar like Delphi's InputBox or InputQuery, what is read a string from a predefined form.
This is like MessageBox is very useful to avoid by-hand form creation.

For example:

```
p1 := InputBox('Type the parameter', 'Parameter 1');
...
```

But I don't found any function.
Can anybody know about it?

Thanks:
   dd

Comment: Are you developing for windows or web?

Comment: Could you please ellaborate your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the C# version of VB.net's InputDialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97097/what-is-the-c-version-of-vb-nets-inputdialog)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which control to use for quick text input (inputbox)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643924/which-control-to-use-for-quick-text-input-inputbox)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [InputBox from the VisualBasic namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox.aspx):

```
var str1 = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Name:", "", "", 100, 100);
```

Just because it is in the `VisualBasic` namespace doesn't mean it is bad!

Answer (score 7):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

public static DialogResult InputBox(string title, string promptText, ref string value)
{
  Form form = new Form();
  Label label = new Label();
  TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
  Button buttonOk = new Button();
  Button buttonCancel = new Button();

  form.Text = title;
  label.Text = promptText;
  textBox.Text = value;

  buttonOk.Text = "OK";
  buttonCancel.Text = "Cancel";
  buttonOk.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
  buttonCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;

  label.SetBounds(9, 20, 372, 13);
  textBox.SetBounds(12, 36, 372, 20);
  buttonOk.SetBounds(228, 72, 75, 23);
  buttonCancel.SetBounds(309, 72, 75, 23);

  label.AutoSize = true;
  textBox.Anchor = textBox.Anchor | AnchorStyles.Right;
  buttonOk.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
  buttonCancel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;

  form.ClientSize = new Size(396, 107);
  form.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { label, textBox, buttonOk, buttonCancel });
  form.ClientSize = new Size(Math.Max(300, label.Right + 10), form.ClientSize.Height);
  form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
  form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
  form.MinimizeBox = false;
  form.MaximizeBox = false;
  form.AcceptButton = buttonOk;
  form.CancelButton = buttonCancel;

  DialogResult dialogResult = form.ShowDialog();
  value = textBox.Text;
  return dialogResult;
}
```

taken from: http://www.csharp-examples.net/inputbox/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [MSDN Forums - Where is the simple dialog prompt (similar to MessageBox)?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/csharplanguage/thread/c7f12f2e-2856-4c66-861b-77e5e19bc753)

To quote the accepted answer:

> There is no such thing...  Unless you
>   are using Visual Basic or specially
>   add a reference to the the
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly.
>
> Once you have added a reference to
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic, you can use
>   code like the following:

```
string s = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter string:", "Data Entry", "", -1, -1);
```

> I would like to say that I find this
>   dialog to be visually "ugly" -- I
>   would recommend that you roll your own
>   dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own window with an Input field OR use the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace from the `Microsoft Visual Basic .NET Runtime` assembly.

Your could would be:

```
string result = Interaction.InputBox("Param1","Param2" ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [post](http://www.csharp-examples.net/inputbox/). I think this is helpful to you.

Comment: In case this link dies, the relevant code is shown in jgauffin's answer which is currently the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

.NET, hence C#, does not have a buit-in input form like *InputBox* in Delphi or *Input Dialog Box* via the *showInputDialog* method in Java.

UPD.
Forgot about the Visual Basic assembly with which it is possible.